# SQL Identity with leading padded variable number of zeros

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need to zero pad my ID column for putting in drop down combo boxes, example

> 001 item text
>
> 101 item text 2

but if the numbers only went to 80, then we should have

> 01 item text
>
> 80 item text

and so on, since I need to write this and allow tens / thousands / millions of items to go in, I don't know how many 0's i need up front.

I have the following

An SQL  Function

```
-- Create a function to add 0's to the left of a string.
--Usage: 
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[LEFTPADNUMERIC]

               (@SourceString VARCHAR(MAX), 

                @FinalLength  INT) 

RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX) 

AS 

  BEGIN 

    RETURN 

      (SELECT Replicate('0',@FinalLength - Len(@SourceString)) + @SourceString) 

  END
```

And it get’s used like this:

```
SELECT T.Id, dbo.LEFTPADNUMERIC(Cast(T.Id AS VARCHAR(32)), (Select LEN(CAST(MAX(Id) as varchar(32))) From Task) ) + SPACE(1) + TT.TaskName
FROM Task T
JOIN TaskTranslation TT ON TT.Id = T.Id AND TT.Language = blah blah blah on and on
```

do you know a better, more efficient way?

Is it going to be calculating max every time, or is sql clever enough to remember that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: SQL is great for data storage and retrieval, it's not really intended for string formatting. You'd generally be better putting the formatting code in your front end. If you do go down the SQL route, you might want to see if RIGHT('00000000000' + @SourceString,@FinalLength) works better for you.

Comment: I'm still not certain about how this requirement works either - when new data is added to the database, all of a sudden these "padded IDs" change length - so it's not like it's useful for the end users (who have to know that "0001" is now "00001" because you've reached 10000 rows).

Comment: Damien, you are correct with the requirement there, but here's hoping they will just get used to it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end it was done in linq to sql, storing the 'Pad Length'

```
/// <summary>
    /// Calculate the amount of padding needed for this object
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private static int _padLength = -1;
    private static int PadLength()
    {
        if (_padLength < 0)
        {
            Aurora.Data.AuroraDataContext db = new AuroraDataContext();
            _padLength = (from r in db.KpiForms select r.Id).Max().ToString().Length;
        }

        return _padLength;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the display value for combo boxes
    /// </summary>
    public string DropDownDisplayTitle
    {
        get
        {
            if (this.Id <= 0) return 0.ToString().PadLeft(PadLength(), '0') + " " + this.Title ;
            return this.Id.ToString().PadLeft(PadLength(), '0') + " " + this.Title ;
        }
    }
```

And that's that, it works, and performance will just have to suffer on this one.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, it would be much easier to add a computed, persisted column to your SQL table that has this padded content:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.YourTable
  ADD PaddedID AS RIGHT('00000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(5)), 5) PERSISTED
```

Being a persisted column, the data is actually stored (not calculated on each access), so it will be fast. Now just select this `PaddedID` column for your drop down box and you're good to go!

Comment: That sounds good, but what if I end up with numbers that are larger than 5 characters long? then my combo box will end up like this:

Comment: 00020, 00010, etc, so we are showing 0's when they are not needed. or when over 5 digits, we end up with them looking out of line :(

Comment: Thanks, using Right in the stored proc cuts execution time by 75%, that's a nice saving :) The function now looks like this: ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[LEFTPADNUMERIC2]

               (@Source INT, 

                @FinalLength  INT) 

RETURNS VARCHAR(32) 

AS 

  BEGIN 

    RETURN 

      (SELECT Right('0000000000000000000' + CAST(@Source AS VARCHAR(32)) , @FinalLength))

  END

Comment: @adudley: I choose 5 chars just as a sample - feel free to increase that to 20, if you like :-)

Comment: ahh! but that was the question! how do we make it dynamic, so we only have enough leading zeros, and not too many. And then as more records are added (moving from 99 to 100 for example) then we need to add'another' leading 0, so it all looks nice :)